# Computing the trace of the sample covariance of projected data

Tags: machine-learning, pca

## Problem

For a given dataset $\{x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, assuming that we project each $x_i$ onto a unit vector $u$, and denote the projected data point as $\tilde{x}_i = (x_i^Tu)u$. I would like to derive an expression for the trace of the sample covariance of the projected data.

## My Attempt

The trace of the sample covariance of the projected data matrix would be the sum of its diagonal entries. So what is required is to find an expression for the projected variance of each point $\tilde{x}_i$.

Solving a simpler problem, I've let the projected data point be instead $u^Tx_i$, leading to the variance $u^TSu$, where $S$ is the data covariance matrix. Then the trace is simply $\sum_{i}diag(u^TSu)$, which is maximized when $u$ is the eigenvector of $S$ with the largest eigenvalue.

Back to the problem at hand, the projected data point $\tilde{x}_i$ is not a scalar. Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by seeing that the projected data point $\tilde{x}_i=(x_i^Tu)u =(u^Tx_i)u$ since $x_i^Tu$ is simply a scalar (of course $a^T=a$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}$). Then the covariance matrix simplifies to,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{S} &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\tilde{x}-\bar{\tilde{x}})(\tilde{x}-\bar{\tilde{x}})^T \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n[(u^Tx_i)u - (u^T\bar{x})u][(u^Tx_i)u - (u^T\bar{x})u]^T \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n u^T(x_i-\bar{x})uu^T(x_i-\bar{x})^Tu \\
&= (u^TSu)u u^T
\end{aligned}
$$
where $S$ is the data covariance matrix. Now, 
$$
\begin{aligned}
tr[(u^TSu)uu^T]&=u^TSu \, \times tr(uu^T) \\
&= u^TSu \, \times u^Tu \\
&=u^TSu 
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: It's not true that $u u^T = 1$; $u$ is $d \times 1$, so $u u^T$ is $d \times d$ (of rank 1). $u$ being a unit vector does mean that $\operatorname{Tr}(u u^T) = u^T u = 1$, but that doesn't particularly help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I see that to be true. I've made the edit, which I think does help after all. Any other corrections are most appreciated!

Comment: The second-to-last line of the main equality chain has a transpose missing; it should be something equivalent to $$\frac1n \sum_{I=1}^n u^T (x_i - \bar x) u u^T (x_i - \bar x)^T u.$$ Then, moving the scalar products around you can indeed get $u^T S u u u^T$ as you did.